# Power switch touch button

Tags: power, switches, lcd, motherboard, backlight

I am building a touch industrial panel PC with an embedded motherboard, an LCD panel and a touch sensor.
I need a touch button to switch power on/off.
I have three questions:

1. How can I switch the motherboard's power ON/OFF with a touch button?
2. Can the LCD be powered by the motherboard or it needs it's own external power source?
3. Can I control the LCD back lights from the OS?

I am using the following LCD panel:
https://www.displaytechnology.co.uk/assets/product_files/g121ean01.2_datasheet.pdf

and this motherboard:
http://www.maxtangpc.com/uploadfile/file/20220830/1661827863903050.pdf
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: 1. No, since a button does not provide power. You need a power source.  2. Depends on the motherboard. What does the datasheet say? 3. Depends on your display. What does the datasheet say?

Comment: 1) We don't know. The electrical interface to motherboard is unknown so we can only guess. 2) The current how much motherboard can provide is unknown so it is unknown if it is enough for the display 3) You have the manual, we don't know which OS you will use and if the motherboars supports it. This is mainly electrical product usage question.